# Should one use nullable type arguments (PHP) in this case (and in general)?

Tags: php, nullable

Consider example:

```
function toCamelCase(?string $string) : string {
    return str_replace('_', '', ucwords($string, ' /_'));
}

function startsWith(?string $search, ?string $str) : bool {
    return mb_strpos($str, $search) === 0;
}
```

The built-in functions being used under the hood are null-argument compatible (although documentation says nothing about it), therefore the code runs without crashes.

So the reasons to allow nulls as arguments were like these ones:

- it's supported by PHP functions;
- it simplifies calling code by not forcing one to check for nulls
  every time;
- it is more flexible to have this option than not to have it;
- this class/method should not be responsible for input validation;
- [your variant?]

Does it look like a thoughtful decision or this code has some disadvantages and consequences that outweigh benefits?

Are there any general rules for using nullable type arguments?

Comment: What you allow becomes your responsibility. I usually think it's best to put the onus on the caller and not widen the function to deflect an error (`null` instead of the string it really needs). It's needless to play defense, in other words, if it only works with strings in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review a basic case:

```
function foo(string $bar): string {
    return substr($bar, 0, 3);
}
```

A substring of `null` makes no sense. So what does the `?` denote? It's a switch to default.

```
function foo(?string $bar): string {
    return substr($bar ?? '', 0, 3);
}
```

Or:

```
function foo(?string $bar = null): string {
    return substr($bar ?? '', 0, 3);
}
```

Does `foo(null)` or `foo()` make any sense? I don't believe the null switch improves the function's response, it only guards against a caller not paying attention.

```
foo($baz ?? '')
```

In this case, I would not widen to include the null scenario, simply because the function has no switch-to-default behavior that's rational.

Comment: If there is no sense to work with nulls then why allow passing null as an argument? Even if there is a swith to default inside function in this case. 
Doesn't it look like an error happens somewhere outside than brings null into the function which is assumed to work with strings? Wouldn't it be better to shut down as soon as possible when corrupted argument usage is discovered?

Comment: Didn't say there's no sense, in this case I don't see why. I use nullable arguments all the time.

Comment: you said "A substring of null makes no sense". Because substring is the only operation the function does, i'd choose not even allow null as its argument.